# Contagem de múltiplos de um inteiro está dando valores muito diferentes do esperado

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Ao receber dois números inteiros, tenho que mostrar quantos múltiplos o número `n1` (digitado 3) tem até chegar ao `n2` (digitado 44).

O resultado correto deveria ser:

> O numero 3 tem **14** multiplos menores que 44.

O problema é que meu resultado está dando:

> O numero 3 tem **6** multiplos menores que 44

Esse é o código:

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
soma = 0
count = -1
for c in range(n1, n2, 2):
  if c % 3 == 0:
    soma += c
    count += 1
print('O numero {} tem {} multiplos menores que {}.'.format(n1, count, n2))
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Imagino que seja isso que deseja:

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
count = 0
for c in range(n1, n2):
    if c % n1 == 0:
        count += 1
print('O numero {} tem {} multiplos menores que {}.'.format(n1, count, n2))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/n3xr9y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gtpfnatm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Count.py).

Não entendi o que a soma faz aí, tirei. Não sei porque resolveu pular de 2 em 2. Pode ter algum motivo, pode ser que o enunciado esteja incompleto ou ambíguo. Eu entendi que o primeiro número digitado seria para indicar os múltiplos.

Eu interpretei que ele mesmo seria um último válido por isso comecei a contagem com 0, mas se realmente ele não deva ser contado deveria começar contar com -1, fui no mais lógico. parece que não pelo resultado que está esperando.

E o maior erro do código é que está usando o múltiplo fixo 3, que parece errado, pode ser até que seja o certo e não está claro, sendo o múltiplo do primeiro número digitado então é essa variável que deve usar como divisor.

Uma forma mais idiomática:

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
count = 0
for c in range(n1, n2, n1):
    count += 1
print('O numero {} tem {} multiplos menores que {}.'.format(n1, count, n2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução alternativa para o problema seria criar uma lista numérica `[n1, n2[` e filtrar seus valores deixando passar apenas os múltiplos de `n1` e contar a quantidade desses valores aprovados.

Para filtrar uma lista usa-se a função builtin [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) que constrói um iterador a partir dos elementos de [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#iterable) para os quais `function` retorna `True`.

A função para filtro é uma função anônima criada com a palavra chave [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
#Se x for múltiplo de n1 retorna True
lambda x: x % n1 == 0
```

Para contar os elementos usa-se a função builtin [`len(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) que devolve o o número de itens de um objeto.

Para facilitar a montagem da string de saída foi usada [`fstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
n1 = int(input("número a ser testado: "))
n2 = int(input("limite do teste: "))

count = len(list(filter(lambda x: x % n1 == 0, range(n1, n2))))

print(f'O numero {n1} tem {count} multiplos menores que {n2}.')
```

Teste no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/LumberingEvenDisassembler

Answer (score 2):

Se a sequência começa com um número `n1` e ela deve ter somente os múltiplos desse número, basta iterar de `n1` em `n1`:

```
count = 0
for _ in range(n1, n2, n1):
    count += 1
```

O terceiro parâmetro de um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) é o *step*. Se ele não é informado, o valor *default* é 1 (ou seja, os números da sequência avançam de 1 em 1). Mas eu posso usar qualquer outro número. Por exemplo, se `n1` for igual a 3, a sequência começa no 3 e vai pulando de 3 em 3 (ou seja, ela será 3, 6, 9, etc...).

> *Aliás, é por isso que seu código não funcionou, pois você usou o step igual a 2, então estava gerando a sequência 3, 5, 7, 9, etc (deixando de fora vários múltiplos de 3, como o 6, 12, 18, etc).*

E como a sequência começa em `n1` e o *step* também é `n1`, então com certeza todos os números do `range` serão múltiplos de `n1`. Por isso eu nem preciso verificar o resto da divisão (e repare que no loop a variável é `_`, que é uma convenção do Python para indicar que não vou usar o valor da variável, já que o que importa é só contar a quantidade de elementos).

Mas como agora só precisamos saber a quantidade de números do `range`, nem precisa de loop, dá para obter isso diretamente com [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
count = len(range(n1, n2, n1))
```

Eu entendo que por ser um exercício, *provavelmente* "querem" que você itere de 1 em 1 e use o operador `%`. Mas para iterar pelos múltiplos de um número, não tem porquê fazer isso, já que você consegue gerar uma sequência que só tem os números que precisa.

---

Só lembrando que se `n2` for múltiplo de `n1`, ele não é incluso na contagem. Por exemplo, se `n1` for 3 e `n2` for 9, o resultado será 2, pois só são considerados o 3 e o 6. Mas se quiser considerar também o 9, basta mudar para `range(n1, n2 + 1, n1)`.

---

Se bem que também dá para resolver só com a boa e velha matemática. Basta dividir `n2` por `n1`, e dependendo do caso, fazer os devidos ajustes.

Se a ideia é **não** contar `n2`, mesmo que ele seja múltiplo de `n1` (ou seja, equivalente a `range(n1, n2, n1)`), basta arredondar o resultado da divisão para cima e subtrair 1:

```
from math import ceil 
count = ceil(n2 / n1) - 1
```

Mas se a ideia é contar `n2` caso ele seja múltiplo de `n1` (ou seja, equivalente a `range(n1, n2 + 1, n1)`), basta fazer a divisão inteira, usando o [operador](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=division#binary-arithmetic-operations) `//`:

```
count = n2 // n1
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Python, você pode solucionar o problema proposto sem qualquer tipo de *loop*, veja só:

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())

count = len(range(n1, n2, n1))

print('O numero {} tem {} multiplos menores que {}.'.format(n1, count, n2))
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/RedundantDoubleTechnician)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi, você pretende `contar` a quantidade de `múltiplos` de um determinado valor que se encontra dentro de um `range` no qual o `menor` valor é `n1` e o `maior` valor é `n2`.

Para resolver esta questão, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
print('=' * 55)
print(f'\033[34m{f"Contador de Múltiplos":^55}\033[m')
print('=' * 55)

while True:
    try:
        n1 = int(input('Digite o limite inferior: '))
        break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apens números inteiros!\033[m')

while True:
    try:
        n2 = int(input('Digite o limite superior: '))
        break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apens números inteiros!\033[m')

cont = 0
for c in range(n1, n2 + 1, n1):
    cont += 1
print(f'\033[32mTemos {cont} múltiplos de {n1} no intervalo fechado [{n1}, {n2}]')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/jsuosqvy-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que este algoritmo possui tratamento de erro e exceção para cada `valor digitado`.

Answer (score -2):

```
    print('-=-'*20)
    print('Multiplos de 3.')
    print('-=-'*20)

    n1 = int(input())
    n2 = int(input())
    cont = 0
    for c in range(n1,n2):
        if c % n1 ==0:
            cont = + 1

   print(f'O numero {n1} tem {count} multiplos menores que {n2}')
```

Veja sim assim vc consegui resolver seu problema.